# AndroidAnnotations update to 3.0.1 doesn't work

Tags: android, eclipse, version, adt, android-annotations

I'm building a project with AA 2.7.1 and it works with no errors.

Now I want to update to [AA 3.0.1](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Download) which is stable since the 12th of Jan 2014. Of course I read the wiki so I've updated both the compiler and the api files in their respective directories; after refreshing the project under the ADT, I changed the active compiler but nothing seems to work anymore. In other words, the new version of the library is not load by the project.

So I replaced the old one, and it works again. What's wrong with AA 3.0.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package names have changed between 2.X and 3.X, have you changed your imports?

[See the version 3.0 release note](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/ReleaseNotes#wiki-3.0).

Comment: Yeah, of course you're right. Click on the project, organize all imports and it's done. Thanks!